# django: Selecting a freign key from 2 models

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing a blog styled application. I want to implement something like custom tags. (Trying to do the tag app myself, so I can learn something).

So I want to be able to create tags in admin interface, and want to be able to assign the to either my Section or Article model. I wonder if that's possible to make an model which will give ability to chose object (e.g. article or section)

I was looking on django comments app, but I would like to do something more simple. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). A generic foreign key enables you to have have a foreign key relationship without having to define the target model in the code.

But I'd recommend to use [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/), which is a ready-made generic django tagging application which provides you a lot of additional functionality and is pretty easy to integrate (it also works via generic relations).